# Triggering ajax service only on enter key, not minimum length select2

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have ajax service that returns results to control, but I can't seem to find solution to trigger ajax search differently.

Now there is a setting to some minimumInputLength, but I need to circumvent that event and only if user enters some custom length text + enter key to send ajax request..

I don't know if that is possible to acheve with select2 and if there is some code snippet that I can check ..

thanks for any ideas

cheers

ghi link: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2213

Answer (score 0):

i just answered a related question: [select2 delete and recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898693/set-json-data-from-ajax-and-make-it-serarchable-in-select2-jquery/22928349#22928349).

i took a look at the [select2 docs](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and agree that it doesn't seem like a supported scenario.  however using the

```
$('#sel').select2("destroy");
```

and

```
$('#sel').select2( $opts );
```

model from the other question, i suspect you can completely externalize this update by building a key down handler for the enter and making the `ajax` call and getting the results back then recreating the `select2` with these results as a static list of options.  don't even tell `select2` that its an ajax typeahead control, you manage that externally.

if you'd like to go down this route, i'd be glad to explore it in more detail with you.